# R and installation command

Tags: r

```
install.packages("car")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/sanzida/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/car_2.1-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1483419 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\sanzida\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCGnD9y\downloaded_packages

library("car")
```

> ```
> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>   there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’**
> ```

I already installed the package and it is seen from the history. But again error message from loading the library. What can I do now?

Comment: Error message is clear, we will need to install `Rcpp` library as well.